# Font-size on iOS with viewport

Tags: html, ios, css, viewport, font-size

I Just can't figure this out.

I'm build an html game and all the game fonts are bigger in my iPhone4 than they are in my pc browser (Chrome).

[image]

I'm using this tag on the html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
```

The font size is set at 4em in the buttons with the "-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;" css property in the whole body.

I know it has something to do with pixel density and the iPhone resolution, but I tried everything and I can't make them both look the same.

If I remove the html viewport tag, then the fonts end up looking much smaller than they're supposed to be.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the appropriate media query for it? 4em on mobile is huge, I normally don't go above 1.2-5 em on mobile sites.

add this in your css

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width:590px){

    /*what ever the element is*/{
    font-size: 1em;
    }

    }
```

Comment: I thought em was adjustable to the device resolution. Same thing if I use percentage in the font size.
And what exactly is the code yous posted doing?

Comment: I've always had to restate the em size I use based off of resolution. My code is saying "In screen sizes of 1px up to 590pxs, do this style instead"  so it will overwrite your 4em in mobile screen sizes

In regards to EM, em is equal to 1 Capital "M" of the current font size, if you never defined your font size, then 4em is 4x the browser standard of 16px. Your fonts at 4em are most like 64px.

Answer (score 0):

You could try use viewport height for your font sizes.

```
 font-size: 5vh;
```

It will scale your text based on the height of the viewport(window) so it should scale aright between browser and mobile.